# displaying numbers in fa_IR locale

Tags: java, numbers, locale

I'm trying to display numbers in `fa_IR` locale.
I'm using this code:

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("fa","IR")).format(myNum);
```

But this prints English (`en_US`) numbers.
How can I display a number in a specific locale in Java?

---

Example:
For example if `myNum` be `12` the output should be `۱۲`

---

Edit:
It seems `java.text.NumberFormat` doesn't support `fa_IR` locale (?).
Using `com.​ibm.​icu.​text.​NumberFormat` instead, fixes the problem!

Comment: can you give your raw number and expected result? I didn't see any difference of number format between Iran and US...  check here http://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/fa_IR/

Comment: @Kent: I added an example; Farsi's numbers are like Arabic numbers.

Comment: @RYN, Hello, have you solved your problem? I want to display Persian numbers in my javaFX application but I couldn't make it.

Answer (score 7):

As you know Oracle (or it's better to say *Java Programming language* ) does not support Persian directly, in order to have a Persian( or Arabic ) NumberFormat you can use the below codes:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab").build());
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(1234567890));
```

The output will be like this:
`۱،۲۳۴،۵۶۷،۸۹۰`
as you can see by using this kind of code your output number not only will be in Persian style but also its each three numbers will be grouped and separated by a **","** character.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("fa"));
System.out.println(nf.format(1234567890));
```

output:

```
۱۲۳٬۴۵۶٬۷۸۹
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String.format(new Locale("fa"), "%d", 123456)
```